# Redirect an HTTP request only if specific media type is preferred

Tags: rest, http, redirect, representation, media-type

In HTTP if a client requests a resource while sending specific media type preferences (through proactive content negotiation aka `Accept` header) and a representation of this resource is not available in the preferred media type.

Would it now be acceptable to redirect the client to a different URI (therefore semantically likely a different resource) which can provide that representation?

At the same time if a client would have requested a media type where there is a representation available for the resource, that representation would then be delivered.

Obviously this would only make sense in situations where the requested media type itself carries some kind of semantic and is not a generic format.

I suspect that this is not intended behavior because the semantics are supposed to be defined by the requested resource. But I would like to know if there are definitions or standards that specifically allow or forbid this kind of server behavior.

Example:

A resource semantically represents a list of articles and a representation of it is available as generic `text/html`. Now the client requests it with a preference for `application/json-home`. The server could know that this media type only makes sense for a semantic home resource and redirect the client to the `/` path of the same site (where the home resource resides). On the other hand if no preference media type would be given, or a `text/html` representation is asked for by a client, this could be served as a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes, it's acceptable to redirect clients to a different URI based on the `Accept` header the client sends, and the HTTP spec explicitly envisions this scenario.

How to do so in a spec-compliant way, including what status codes you return, depends on the nature of your resource and the client(s) you're serving. Here are a few options:

### 406 (Not Acceptable)

RFC 7231 seems to prefer the `406 (Not Acceptable)` status code in this scenario. From [section 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2):

```
If the [Accept] header field is
present in a request and none of the available representations for
the response have a media type that is listed as acceptable, the
origin server can either honor the header field by sending a 406 (Not
Acceptable) response or disregard the header field by treating the
response as if it is not subject to content negotiation.
```

Even though the response is a 4xx client error, [section 6.5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6) explicitly allows for automatic selection of other resources and/or media types that would be acceptable to the server:

```
The server SHOULD generate a payload containing a list of available
representation characteristics and corresponding resource identifiers
from which the user or user agent can choose the one most
appropriate.  A user agent MAY automatically select the most
appropriate choice from that list.  However, this specification does
not define any standard for such automatic selection, as described in
Section 6.4.1.
```

In your example scenario, the payload of your response could contain a link to the "home" resource and indicate that it can be retrieved with the `application/json-home` media type. (It could also contain a link to this same resource, indicating it can be retrieved with one or more other media types.)

Though a 406 is not a redirect (in the 3xx sense), the spec explicitly allows a client to automatically follow the link(s) in your 406 response. A web browser would not do so automatically, however.

### 303 (See Other)

You could also use a `300 (Multiple Choices)` or a `303 (See Other)`, both of which explicitly specify a `Location` header which the user agent can use to retrieve the alternate URI. If you do need *automatic* redirection, and your client is a common web browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.), then the most practical response is probably to have your server return a `303 (See Other)`. From [RFC 7231, section 6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4):

```
The 303 (See Other) status code indicates that the server is
redirecting the user agent to a different resource, as indicated by a
URI in the Location header field, which is intended to provide an
indirect response to the original request.  A user agent can perform
a retrieval request targeting that URI (a GET or HEAD request if
using HTTP), which might also be redirected, and present the eventual
result as an answer to the original request.  Note that the new URI
in the Location header field is not considered equivalent to the
effective request URI.
[...]
A 303 response to a GET request indicates that the origin server does
not have a representation of the target resource that can be
transferred by the server over HTTP.  However, the Location field
value refers to a resource that is descriptive of the target
resource, such that making a retrieval request on that other resource
might result in a representation that is useful to recipients without
implying that it represents the original target resource.
```

With the 303, the server is explicitly saying, "This URI I'm redirecting you to is not equivalent to the URI you wanted, but I think it might be close." This seems pretty close to what you were asking for, and as long as you provide a preferred URI in the `Location` header, browsers (and many other HTTP clients) will follow the redirect automatically.

### 300 (Multiple Choices)

`300 (Multiple Choices)` is also an option. It's designed more for redirecting users to one of multiple alternative URIs for a resource as part of reactive content negotiation (see [section 3.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4.2)).

[RFC 7231, section 6.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.1):

```
The 300 (Multiple Choices) status code indicates that the target
resource has more than one representation, each with its own more
specific identifier, and information about the alternatives is being
provided so that the user (or user agent) can select a preferred
representation by redirecting its request to one or more of those
identifiers.  In other words, the server desires that the user agent
engage in reactive negotiation to select the most appropriate
representation(s) for its needs (Section 3.4).

If the server has a preferred choice, the server SHOULD generate a
Location header field containing a preferred choice's URI reference.
The user agent MAY use the Location field value for automatic
redirection.
```

Though it doesn't appear to violate the spec to selectively return a 300 based on the client's supported media type, a 406 would be more intuitive.

### `Vary: accept` header

No matter what status code you return, you should include the `Vary: accept` header in ALL responses for this URI, including the 200 (or any other) response sent when the client makes the request with the acceptable media type for this resource. The `Vary` header is explicitly designed for reactive content negotiation, and it will prevent a (compliant) intermediary or client from serving the "wrong" response to a request with a different `Accept` header. See [section 7.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4) for details.

Comment: Your response is brilliant. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the description of 300 (Multiple Choices) assumes that different represenations for the same resource are selectable through different URIs? Because otherwise the `Location` header part would be the same URI as requested, right?

Comment: Technically, the 300 only means there are different "representations" of the resource, not that there are different URIs. Those "representations" may or may not be available at different URIs. The 300 response could, for example, contain links to the same URI but with an indication to the client that different media types should/could be used. The `Location` header simply means the server is saying "I 'prefer' you use this URI, and you can try your request using this URI again without asking a user, if you desire."